# Defining the event

Tags: javascript

I understood how to create events, like that:

```
var evt=document.createEvent('Event');
evt.initEvent('foo',true,true);
window.dispatch(evt);
```

Then anyone can write : `window.addEventListener("foo",myFunc,false);` (just for safari)

But I didn't understand where I define the tests of the event `foo`. For exemple, if the event is `shake`, where do I write the tests if the iPhone is shaked or not?

Comment: I'm not getting the question. What does it mean _"where do I write the tests"_

Comment: Where do I define what foo does?

Comment: I"m afraid I'm still not getting it. :(

Comment: Do you want to listen for the shake event? If so, I can recommend shake.js: https://github.com/alexgibson/shake.js/blob/master/shake.js.

Comment: Do you mean "how do I write an event listener for my event"?

Comment: Look this website : http://alexgibson.github.com/shake.js/. Look the source code. you can see that they wrote `window.addEventListener('shake', shakeEventDidOccur, false);`. Where do they write the `if` to test if the iPhone is shaked?

Comment: In http://alexgibson.github.com/shake.js/shake.js. All of http://alexgibson.github.com/shake.js/shake.js.

Comment: okay but in my simple exemple, for a simple test, where do I write it?

Comment: Where do you write … what? The first block of code in the question? You fire the event when you want the event to fire. We don't know when you want it to fire, and the name `foo` doesn't give us the first clue as to when you want it to fire.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I write the code to detect shaking" (in which case look to see where they dispatch the event) or "where do I put the code I want to execute when the phone has been shaken" (in which case in the function you attach to the event)?

Comment: @Quentin no! in myFunc you write what you want to do if `shaked` or `clicked` or `foo`. but where do I define `foo`????????

Comment: @DaveNewton `where do I put the code I want to execute when the phone has been shaken` and how do I return that the iPhone is shaked or not (I know already how to detect)

Comment: @user1365010 — It depends on what you want `foo` to indicate. You write the code somewhere where it will be fired what that happens.

Comment: @user1365010 — When the phone in shaken? You use the library you linked to. You use the correct name for the event (which isn't `foo`). And you put the code in `myFunc`.

Comment: ... Wherever you want. We don't know what it is. You dispatch the event whenever the event happens.

Comment: I'm exhausted. I'm getting breakfast.

Comment: You must first add listeners (with `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` (IE)) and then use `dispatchEvent` or `fireEvent` (IE) to trigger *YOUR CUSTOM foo* event. When you call `dispatchEvent` all registered listeners-functions for *YOUR CUSTOM foo* event are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, it's :

```
if(shaked)window.dispatch(evt);
```

I thought we always had to write

```
window.dispatch(evt);
```

and then

```
if(shaked)return true; //or something like that
```